# Различия префиксных операторов инкремента/декремента в С и C++

Tags: c++, c

Игрался с вот таким кодом на VS:

```
int a;
int b = !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!a;
int c = ++++++++++++++++++++++++++a;
int d = --------------------------a;
```

И вот что получилось - если компилировать как C - то пишет, что для `++` и `--` требуется левостороннее значение. Но если компилировать как C++, то компилирует без ошибок.

Не понимаю, в чем разница, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Зачем столько лишнего кода? Для демонстрации вопроса достаточно `int a; int c = ++++a;`. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PinkTux: На SO обсуждают только конкретно заданные вопросы, а для всего другого служат кнопки и одна из них это "правка", которая модерируется сообществом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В C++ значением префиксных (унарных) оператора ++ и -- является `lvalue` , в то время как в C это `rvalue`, то есть временный объект, который нельзя изменить.

Сравните также для примера оператор присвоения. В C++ вы можете написать таким образом

```
int i;
int j = 10;

( i = 5 ) += j;
```

В C же такой код выполняться не будет так как оператор приисваивания возвращает `rvalue`.

Из стандарта C (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
>   The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The
>   expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1). See the discussions of
>   additive operators and compound assignment for information on
>   constraints, types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of
>   operations on pointers.

V (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
>   the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment,111) but is **not an lvalue**.

Из стандарта C++ (5.3.2 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if
>   it is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable
>   lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a
>   pointer to a completely-defined object type. The result is the updated
>   operand; it is an **lvalue**, and it is a bit-field if the operand is
>   a bit-field. If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x is
>   equivalent to x+=1 [ Note: See the discussions of addition (5.7) and
>   assignment operators (5.17) for information on conversions. —end note
>   ]

Что касается оператора логического отрицания, то оно применяется к выражениям и эквивалентно выражению `e == 0`

Из стандарта C (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
>   converted to bool (Clause 4); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

И из стандарта C++ (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
>   converted to bool (Clause 4); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

В программах на C можно нередко встретить двойное отрицание, примененное к выражению

```
!!expression
```

Это делается для того, чтобы результат выражения был равен в точности `0` или `1`.

Comment: Мне сложновато продраться через эти цитаты на английском, но врод главное я понял.. Только, если это не совсем дурацкий вопрос - почему? Я демал, что C++ по максимуму делали похожим на C, по крайцней мере в основных вещах - а тут такая разница? Почему в C++ пошли иначе, чем в C?

Comment: @Mikhailo Я сейчас не могу ответить на этот вопрос. Но, думаю, в книге Страуструпа, где он пишет про эволюцию C++, которой у меня сейчас нет под рукой, наверное указана причина. Возможно, что это как-то связано с возможностью перегрузки операторов в C++, чтобы, например, избежать лишнего копирования создаваемого временного объекта.

Comment: @Mikhailo, разница проста: ссылки. В C++ они есть, а в C их нет. Без ссылок реализовать `++` как lvalue нельзя. Конечно, стандарт мог бы потребовать такого поведения и компиляторы бы это выполнили, но я подозреваю, что `++i` сделали возвращающим lvalue исключительно ради перегруженных вариантов оного, а обратный порт в C никто не стал делать — нет смысла ломать, то, что и так работает. Тем более, что для C это особого смысла не имеет.

Comment: @ixSci Спасибо!