# Ошибка lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, указатели, синтаксис

Есть три (независимые) строчки кода:

```
1) *a++ = 5;
2) *(a++) = 5;
3) (*a)++ = 5;
```

Первая и вторая строчки работают одинаково.
На третью компилятор (minGW, GCC) ругается:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>        (*a)++=5;

Не могу понять почему. Теоретически она не должна отличаться от первых двух: разыменовываем указатель `a`, присваиваем  новое значение, выполняем  постфиксный инкремент указателя. Расстановка скобок в левой части не должна влиять на порядок выполнения, но такое впечатление, что в третьем случае влияет, и код выглядит так:

```
((*a) + 1) = 5;
```

Только в таком случае действительно не выполняется условие `lvalue`.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему на самом деле я получаю ошибку компиляции, и какая разница между первыми двумя строчками кода и третьей, а так же что является операндом для постфиксного инкремента (указатель или разлинованная область).

Comment: Я уже спрашивал :) - здесь отвечено: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594789/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%a1-%d0%b8-c

Comment: @Mikhailo Нет, у вас там несколько другой вопрос. Как минимум о префиксном операторе.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B, читайте главу Operator precedence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
*a++ = 5;
```

Сначала применение `++` к `a`, возврат старого указателя, разыменование, присвоение.

```
*(a++) = 5;
```

Сначала инкремент, который возвращает старый указатель, который разыменовывается, и по этому адресу выполняется присваивание (все, как в первой строке).

```
(*a)++ = 5;
```

Разыменование, получаем значение,  к которому применяем `++`... к чему? К разыменованному значению указателя? OK, но что при этом вернуть? Просто старое значение в памяти по этому адресу?

Ссылок в C нет, это не C++. Значит, вернуть просто *старое значение* 5? Но это не lvalue! на что, сообственно, и указывает компилятор....

*По-моему, так* (с) Пух

Comment: Удалил комментарий :-)